# Searchable Option List (jQuery plugin), get selected value in php

Tags: php, jquery-plugins

I'm using 
https://pbauerochse.github.io/searchable-option-list/examples.html plugin in my website for searchable dropdown. its working perfectly but i don't know how to get the value of selected items in PHP?
I try to use below code but it return only last selected value in dropdown:

```
//echo count($_POST['courses']); 
// it return only 1 but I select more than 5 items

if (!empty($_POST['courses'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['courses'] as $select) {
        echo $coursename .= $select. " "; 
        // only last selected value is displaying
    }
}
```

any one please help...

Comment: you should write name like this: `<select name="courses[]" multiple="multiple">`

Comment: thanks alots its working....